# Is it possible with androidviewclient to search for multiple words in findveiwwithtext() function?

Tags: android, python-2.7, androidviewclient

I am using `Androidviewclient` `version 11.5.6` and I want to search for multiple names at a time in function `findVeiwwithtext` function. Is it possible with `AVC`??

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using this function for operating a powerSwitch. I am curious that if the findViewWithTextOrRaise() function can search for two words like ON, OFF at a time and should accept if any of them is available. Now I am calling function as  `com_csr_csrmeshdemo___id_powerSwitch = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'ON').touch()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `findViewWithTextOrRaise()` accepts a `RegexType` (see [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)) as parameter so you can use patterns if your intention is to match more than one View.

As a starting point you can invoke `culebra --use-regexps ...` and it will generate statements like this

```
no_id26 = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'Phone'))
```

which you can easily adapt to your needs. For example

```
    no_id26 = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'(Phone)|(Settings)'))
```

this will match Phone or Settings.

Comment: Thank You Very much!! Works cool for my requirement. But getting error when I use re.compile with code generated by culebra GUI
`$ culebra --scale=0.5 -uUG -o sript.py `

Comment: If you show your code and the error perhaps you can obtain some help, otherwise it's fairly impossible to guess. If this answers resolved some of your problems accept it a create a new one to keep things organized in **SO** and help others looking for same answers.

Comment: The code with which I am getting errors is: 
`self.vc.dump(window=-1)
self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'(OFF)|(ON)')).touch()
self.vc.sleep(6)`